# LDAP bind with uid

Tags: ldap, authentication, svn, openldap

We're currently using an LDAP server that is built into a QNAP NAS box but we are aiming to move away from that and host our own OpenLDAP server. We've already set this up and have had some success in validating against it with some of our services.

However, some of our applications (namely SVN) are not working. These are the settings that we have in dav_svn.conf:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthName "Subversion Repository"

AuthBasicAuthoritative on

AuthLDAPBindDN "uid=svnuser,ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=local"
AuthLDAPBindPassword ***

AuthLDAPURL "ldaps://x.x.x.x:636/dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=local"
```

However, this does not work when the new LDAP server is substituted. After some experimentation I am wondering if it is down to the way that the new LDAP server is configured:

The distinguished name for this user is "cn=SVN User,ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=local" in the new LDAP server, although it does have a uid field that is set to svnuser. I am trying to bind against "uid=svnuser,ou=people,dc=ldap,dc=test,dc=local".

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just solved this one myself after a bit more Googling...

I didn't mention before but I am using phpLDAPAdmin and you need to edit the posixAccount.xml template file (/etc/phpldapadmin/templates/creation/posixAccount.xml).

Edit that file and change the following:

```
<rdn>cn</rdn>
```

to:

```
<rdn>uid</rdn>
```

Hope this helps others in the same boat.